# how wait to show move by key in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, events

i have this method ,
and i need the app to wait until show the action in gui by move method 
how i do that ?

```
void move (char c)
    {
        if (c == 't' || c == 'k')
        {
            KeyEventArgs e1 = new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource, 0, Key.Down) { RoutedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent };
            InputManager.Current.ProcessInput(e1);

        }
        else if (c == 'l')
        {
            KeyEventArgs e1 = new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource, 0, Key.Left) { RoutedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent };
            InputManager.Current.ProcessInput(e1);
        }
        else if (c == 'r')
        {
            KeyEventArgs e1 = new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource, 0, Key.Right) { RoutedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent };
            InputManager.Current.ProcessInput(e1);
        }


        //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Timer.Stop();
    }
```

Comment: i try Sleep() and timer but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you either want to have your action thread sample the keyboard when it runs and then action on what is pressed rather than on an event

or

use your event to set a pending action flag on your VM and then have your action thread use that as your input not the keyboard

here is an example this approach

this application after you press the checkbox will write your action to the screen every 2 seconds

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_ScratchPad"
    xmlns:ComponentModel="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase" 
    x:Class="WPF_ScratchPad.MainWindow"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Height="350"
    Width="525" KeyUp="Window_KeyUp">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:VM/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Gesture="Up" Command="{Binding SetAction}" >
            <KeyBinding.CommandParameter>
                <local:GameAction>MoveUp</local:GameAction>
            </KeyBinding.CommandParameter>
        </KeyBinding>
        <KeyBinding Gesture="Down" Command="{Binding SetAction}" >
            <KeyBinding.CommandParameter>
                <local:GameAction>MoveDown</local:GameAction>
            </KeyBinding.CommandParameter>
        </KeyBinding>
        <KeyBinding Gesture="Left" Command="{Binding SetAction}" >
            <KeyBinding.CommandParameter>
                <local:GameAction>MoveLeft</local:GameAction>
            </KeyBinding.CommandParameter>
        </KeyBinding>
        <KeyBinding Gesture="Right" Command="{Binding SetAction}" >
            <KeyBinding.CommandParameter>
                <local:GameAction>MoveRight</local:GameAction>
            </KeyBinding.CommandParameter>
        </KeyBinding>
    </Window.InputBindings>
    <StackPanel>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Running}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ActionText}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code behind

```
private void Window_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    (DataContext as VM).Action = GameAction.None;
}
```

Actions are defined as

```
public enum GameAction
{
    None,
    MoveUp,
    MoveDown,
    Moveleft,
    MoveRight,
}
```

and the ViewModel as

```
public class VM:BindableBase
{
    public VM()
    {
        SetAction = new DelegateCommand<GameAction?>(a => Action = a ?? GameAction.None);
    }

    private string _ActionText;

    public string ActionText
    {
        get { return _ActionText; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _ActionText, value); }
    }

    private bool _Running = false;

    public bool Running
    {
        get { return _Running; }
        set
        {
            if(SetProperty(ref _Running, value))
            {
                if (Running)
                    StartGame();
            }
        }
    }


    public GameAction Action { get; set; }
    public DelegateCommand<GameAction?> SetAction { get; set; }
    public Task ActionThread { get; set; }

    public void StartGame()
    {
        if (ActionThread == null)
        {
            ActionThread = Task.Run((Action) GameLoop); 
        }
    }
    public async void GameLoop ()
    {
        while(Running)
        {
            switch (Action)
            {
                case GameAction.MoveUp:
                    ActionText += $"{DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()} Up";
                    break;
                case GameAction.MoveDown:
                    ActionText += $"{DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()} Down";
                    break;
                case GameAction.Moveleft:
                    ActionText += $"{DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()} Left";
                    break;
                case GameAction.MoveRight:
                    ActionText += $"{DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()} Right";
                    break;
                default:
                    ActionText += $"{DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()} No Move";
                    break;
            }

            await Task.Delay(2000);//wait 2 seconds
        }
        ActionThread = null;
    }
}
```

note Using Prism